# OpenVPN продолжает работать после закрытия портов на роутере

Tags: openvpn, port

Есть такой интересный вопрос, я настроил сервер openVPN у себя дома, он находится за NAT, но у меня белый ip, поэтому проброс портов всё решает. Я настроил у себя дома веб сервер, к которому получают доступ только несколько человек, поэтому я решил спрятать его за vpn. Клиент получает доступ к openVPN через android приложение клиента openVPN.

Я пробрасываю порты к службе openVPN, клиент подключается, и всё работает отлично.

Но когда я закрываю порты на роутере, то есть доступа к ним из WAN получить уже никак нельзя, клиент который подключился к серверу openVPN тогда когда потры были ещё открыты, имеет доступ к openVPN...

То есть когда он отправляет запрос куда-то, этот запрос проходит через сервер openVpn, его соединение с сервером не пропадает, но никто другой не может уже к openVPN подключиться так как потры закрыты. Если клиент у которого всё еще есть соединение с сервером отключается от него, то подключиться обратно уже не может, логично.

Как так? Почему когда я зыкрываю порты на роутере, клиенты которые уже подключились к openVPN имеют к нему доступ, но если кто-то захочет подключиться, не сможет этого сделать.

Я не сильно разбираюсь в этом, буду рад если кто-то объяснит это поведение. Благодарю заранее :) !!!

Comment: Потому что пакеты внутри устоявшегося соединения идут с флагом ESTABLISHED

Comment: @alex, спасибо, понял. Я в openVPN не знаток, сразу приходит вопрос, я использую соединение tcp, если злоумышленник правильно угадает порядковый номер tcp-сегментов между сервером и клиентом, он сможет вот так просто подключиться к серверу? Или openVPN использует какую-то защиту против этого? Я гуглил на счет этого, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: Впн авторизует по ключам. Ну и вы можете переключиться на udp

Comment: @alex, есть ли повод переходить на `udp`? Мне кажется что `tcp` безопаснее в плане подмены `ip`.